# Get products collection from category id on homepage phtml file

Tags: category-products

```
$categoryId = 'category_id';
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$collection = $productFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$collection->setPageSize(5)->load();

foreach($collection as $products){
// print_r($products->getData());   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection;
}
```

**Using Object Manager**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

$categoryId = 21; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    //print_r($product->getData());
    // printing category name and url
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```